# IOS 7.0.4 Sprint 15.5 Unlocked, Data-Network not working

Tags: iphone

I am using iPhone 5 16GB, IOS 7.0.4 Unlocked Sprint USA....my service provide is Airtel below are the problems I am facing: Network: Yes,Data Network: No,APN Setting Not Showing, carrier: sprint 15.5.
Can anyone guide me or help me plss...I am trying to find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you can only use an unlocked sprint iphone 5 on tmobile with edge network connection. Here is the info that I have found.

> Sprint/Cricket/Virgin Mobile iPhone 5 can only be unlocked for T-Mobile / Simple Mobile and may only get Edge. It may also have issues with data/mms so you may or may not get internet or MMS (picture messaging). This is happening to some Sprint iPhone 5 devices and we are working on a fix. THERE ARE NO REFUNDS IF YOU HAVE A SPRINT iPhone 5 and experience issues with data/mms.

Comment: Can you add the source (link if possible) for your quote?

Answer (score -1):

Us sprint 15.5 iOS 7.0.6 unlock

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! 
This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.